# In the End of CV, I want to add my Educational Degrees. Want to make One PDF?

Tags: floats, diagrams, moderncv, cv

I am apply in university for Master degree they say to me One PDF in which it have CV+Cover Letter+ Educational Degree + Reference Letter.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes:   a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans  or roman

\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

%\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{4.5cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name
\newcommand{\ingreen}[1]{{\color{blue}#1}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{\textsc{First}} % Your first name
\familyname{\textsc{Last Name}} % Your last name
%---------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
% defines one's email (optional)
% usage: \email{<email adress>}
\newcommand*{\skype}[1]{\def\@skype{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\makecvfooter}{%
\setlength{\footerwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyfoot[c]{%
\parbox[b]{\footerwidth}{%
    \centering%
    \color{color2}\addressfont%
    \vspace{\baselineskip}% forces a white line to ensure space between main text and footer (as footer height can't be known in advance)
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofooter[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
      \flushfooter\@firstfooterelementtrue\\}%
    \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
      \addtofooter{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofooter{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofooter{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@skype}}{}{\addtofooter{\includegraphics[height=.7\baselineskip]{skype_gray-crop}~\@skype}}%
    \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
      \addtofooter{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofooter{\@extrainfo}}%
    \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\footerboxwidth=0pt}}{}{\flushfooter}% the lengthtest is required to avoid flushing an empty footer, which could cause a blank line due to the \\ after the address, if no other personal info is used
    }}}%
\pagestyle{plain}}
\makeatother


%---------------------------------------------------

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
%\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Street Number}{City, Country ZipCode}
\mobile{(+00000)000000}
\phone{(+0000) 000000}
\fax{(000) 111 1113}
\skype{abcd}
\email{abcd@gmail.com}
\photo[60pt][0.4pt]{234}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Objective
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Objective}

\cvitem{}{Write the objective about your career.}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Experience}

%\subsection{Vocational}
\cvitem{Aug 2013 $\--$ Jan 2014}{\textbf{Post Name}}
\cvitem{}{\textsc{University Name}}
\cvitem{}{\textsc{City},\textsc{Country}}
\cvitem{}{\textbf{Project}}
\cvitem{}{Write about the Project}
\cvitem{}{\textbf{Responsibilities}}
\cvitem{}{\begin{itemize}
            \item
            \item
            \item   
        \end{itemize}}
%------------------------------------------------
\cvitem{Oct 2009 $\--$ Apr 2013}{\textbf{Post Name}}
\cvitem{}{\textsc{University Name}}
\cvitem{}{\textsc{City},\textsc{Country}}
\cvitem{}{Write about experience}
\cvitem{}{\textbf{Responsibilities}}
\cvitem{}{\begin{itemize}
        \item
        \item
        \item
        \item   
      \end{itemize}}


%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education}
\cvitem{2010 $\--$ 2012}{\textbf{Master}}
\cvitem{}{\textsc{University},\textsc{City},\textsc{Country}}
\cvitem{2006 $\--$ 2010}{\textbf{BS(Hons)}}
\cvitem{}{\textsc{University},\textsc{City},\textsc{Country}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMPUTER SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Area of Interest}

\section{Computer skills}

\cvitem{Intermediate}{\textsc{Tikz}, \textsc{jPicEdt}, \textsc{LaTeX Draw}}
\cvitem{Advanced}{\textsc{LaTeX}, \textsc{Matlab}, \textsc{Mayura Draw}, \textsc{MS Office}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMMUNICATION SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
%   LANGUAGES SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Languages}

\cvitemwithcomment{English}{Advance}{Conversationally fluent}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTERESTS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Hobbies $\&$ Interests}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{-~} % Changes the symbol used for lists

\cvlistdoubleitem{Cricket}{Football}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Cooking}{Chess}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Movies}{Photography}
\cvlistitem{Watching Sports Channels}


%\newpage
\section{Interpersonal Skills}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{-~} % Changes the symbol used for lists


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Personal Information
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Personal Information}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   References
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{References}
\cvlistitem{
\begin{itemize}
\item Prof. Name\\
 Email: \ingreen{abc@mail.edu}\\
 Phone: 000000000 Ext. 000\\
 Department Name\\
 University, City, Country.
 \end{itemize}}


 %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 %  COVER LETTER
 %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 % To remove the cover letter, comment out this entire block

 \clearpage
 \section{\textsc{Cover Letter}}
 \recipient{{\textsc{\ingreen{University}}}}{Country} % Letter recipient
 \date{\today} % Letter date
 \opening{Dear Sir,} % Opening greeting
 \closing{Sincerely yours,} % Closing phrase
 %\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}} % List of enclosed documents

 \makelettertitle % Print letter title

 The following attachment is my resume(C.V) with cover letter. If you are looking for  the responsible and hardworking individual who works as a team member as well as individual. I believe I would valuable asset to your Institute. If you need any additional information, Please feel free to contact me anytime.
 If your Institute had an opportunity in present or near future. I look forward to hearing from you in the near future. 

%\makeletterclosing % Print letter signature


 %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are familiar with this website and I think you do understand that your question, as it is right now, is begging for close votes. Please make it clear what you want to achieve clearly and perhaps, you might want to convert your working example into a minimal one.

Comment: @Pouya I am apply in university for Master degree they say to me One PDF in which it have CV+Cover Letter+ Educational Degree + Reference Letter.

Comment: @LaTeXKhan: I my opinion, it is not the purpose of TeX.SX to provide out of the box solutions which is basically what you request in many of your questions. As Pouya stated, it is provoking close votes, in my opinion due to various reasons: Unclear question or `do it for me` questions.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to first prepare all the documents in separate pdf files and then compile them into a single pdf file using some third party softwares. For example, if you are using OS X, `preview.app` can do this and in Ubuntu there are [different](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2799/how-to-merge-several-pdf-files) options.

If you want a pure latex solution, then you can use [pdfpages](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) to merge all your documents to a single pdf file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
    \includepdf[pages=-]{CV.pdf}
    \includepdf[pages=-]{recomm1.pdf}
    \includepdf[pages=-]{recomm2.pdf}
    \includepdf[pages=-]{transcription.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Just to be sure all your files have the same paper size.

#### Edit

As Rüdiger correctly mentioned in the comments, you need to specify pages you want to include. `pdfpages` documentation states:

> ...The argument is a comma separated list, containing page numbers
> (pages={3,5,6,8}), ranges of page numbers (pages={4-9}) or any
> combination. To insert empty pages use {}. E.g.: pages={3,{},8-11,15}
> will insert page 3, an empty page, and pages 8, 9, 10, 11, and 15.
>
> Page ranges are specified by the following syntax: m - n . This
> selects all pages from m to n . Omitting m defaults to the first page;
> omit- ting n defaults to the last page of the document. Another way to
> select the last page of the document, is to use the keyword last.
> (This is only permitted in a page range.) E.g.: pages=- will insert
> all pages of the document, and pages=last-1 will insert all pages in
> reverse order. (Default: pages=1)

Comment: You should be aware that `\includepdf` by default includes only the first page of any document. So if any of your documents is longer you have to specify that. To inlude all pages use `\includepf[pages=-]{doc.pdf}` . A good third party tool for the same purpose is pdftk.

Comment: @RüdigerVoigt, indeed you are right. Thanks for the heads-up.